# How to get the size of UILabel from a dynamic UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, ios9

I am trying to place a bubble imageView as a superview of a label. The tv cell is dynamical and so the label. I can't get the right width and height of the label in order to change the frame of the bubble. If I have 10 cells and then call the scroll to bottom method, the bubble is well drawn. How can I get the correct width and height of label when first showing the table view?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes, i have constraints on elements of dynamic cell.

Comment: I assume you have a custom cell class for this tv cell (if not, create it), inside  - (void)layoutSubviews you can get the frame of the label (after calling super).

Comment: You are using Auto Layout, then you should forget about the frame. Because normally when we are using Auto Layout, we do not deal with the frame directly. What you need to do is to set the correct constraints on the imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant me, if not I'm sorry ;-)

The answer:

I assume you have a custom cell class for this tv cell (if not, create it), inside - (void)layoutSubviews you can get the frame of the label (after calling super).